# OData lambda, any, with logical operator, and, doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, odata

I want to filter the Outlook Email [messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/message?view=graph-rest-1.0) that have both "Blue category" and "Green category". However, the following request return an empty result.

However, it seems like this issue only happens to personal Outlook account. I tried with another Office 365 account and that one works fine.

Does anyone know if I missed something?

### Request

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(a:a eq 'Green category') and categories/any(a:a eq 'Blue category')`

### Response

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('calvin.kloudless%40outlook.com')/messages",
    "value": []
}
```

I confirmed I had some messages that have aforementioned two categories.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(a:a eq 'Blue category')&$select=categories`

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('calvin.kloudless%40outlook.com')/messages(categories)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaV9\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEJAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR_hoAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category",
                "Green category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaUU\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEMAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR4nQAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category",
                "Green category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaUW\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEJAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR_hgAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category",
                "Green category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaUY\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEMAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR4nMAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category",
                "Green category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaUa\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEJAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR_hcAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category",
                "Green category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaRv\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEMAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR4nIAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category"
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAACY6nZ17sf0Srd6ntecsx9MAADWDaRx\"",
            "id": "AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC0yNDNjLTQ2YzctMDACLTAwCgBGAAAD93y4_KZIZkiUUt1tg8r_0QcAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAAgEJAAAAmOp2de7H9Eq3ep7XnLMfTAAAANXR_hYAAAA=",
            "categories": [
                "Blue category"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Calvin, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use '&' symbol as operator, don't use 'and'. Use below HTTP call.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=categories/any(a:a eq 'Green category')&categories/any(a:a eq 'Blue category')
```

It worked for me as you can see below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ths one works. However, I'm curious why the "and" operator doesn't work. It seem in the OData 4.0 spec (http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_And).

Comment: Also, the "and" operator is also documented in the Graph v1.0 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#filter-parameter)

Comment: Hm... that is also a bit weird. The & indicate there is another query string, "categories/any(a:a eq 'Blue category')" in the URI.